This website cannot be correctly scraped even with requets-html
i'm trying to get the prices displayed on :

https://campervans.jeanlain.com/locations/?city-input=annecy&city-name=ANNECY&departure_date=06%2F01%2F2025&departure_time=11%3A00&return_date=10%2F01%2F2025&return_time=10%3A00

I tried with requests, and requests-html but neither works...
Here is my code :
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = session.get('https://campervans.jeanlain.com/locations/?city-input=annecy&city-name=ANNECY&departure_date=06%2F01%2F2025&departure_time=11%3A00&return_date=10%2F01%2F2025&return_time=10%3A00')
response.html.render()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all('section', class_='product')

for product in products:
    title = product.find('h2', class_='woocommerce-loop-product__title')
    if title:
        print(title.text)
    
    price_info = product.find('div', class_='content-right')
    if price_info:
        price = price_info.find('p', class_='price')
        print(price)
    else:
        print("content-right not found")

The problem is that the "content-right" div is displayed on the page but not in the response... It seems to be loaded with javascript...
How to get the prices displayed with python requests only when the javascript is loaded ? I don't want to use Selenium...
Thanks :)

"Is there a way get the prices ?" Yes, you can either evaluate the JavaScript code or simulate it and directly access the API.

@jabaa i edited my post, the question is "how to get the prices displayed with python requests only when the javascript is loaded ?"

Try selenium.

@MSH "I don't want to use Selenium..."

I'm not sure if requests_html uses already selenium or it uses PyQt (QWebKit) to simulate browser and run JavaScript. Maybe you have to sleep() to wait before  rendering data.

@furas According to https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html, it uses pyppeteer and pyppeteer uses pupeteer, but it's unmaintained: https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer

@jabaa thanks :) Meanwhile I was checking requests-html page for this information :) Now I try find out if requests_html has access to puppeteer to control if object exists on page - like in selenium.

based on documentation you can use render(..., sleep=...) to wait for results - it may gives JavaScript time to render all information. It can also use render(... script=...) to run JavaScript code - it may allow to execute code which can get some item or click some element.

You might have better luck with requests_html2

If you do a little research on html, specifically the script tag in which this variable const ajaxurl = "https://campervans.jeanlain.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"; is defined, you will see how the "client" itself does it. So you just need to do it again, but in python. You can see it in my reply, maybe it will be useful for someone.

I don't know if there is method to check if JavaScript already finished work but it allows to use parameter sleep and JavaScript may have time for work.
response.html.render(sleep=3)

and it gives you results.

It also allows to send JavaScript code which could check if element exists
response.html.render(script="...")

but I don't have any code for this. And probably it would also need to use sleep for this.

Last idea: selenium has functions Waits which run loop and it checks periodically if element already exists.
And requests_html has option keep_page
request_html.html.render(keep_page=True)

which allows to interact with the browser page through html.page.
And you could use it to check periodically if element already exists.

BTW:
I get result without sleep when I don't use BeautifulSoup but built-in functions to search data. Maybe these functions already use some longer time to check if object exists. Or maybe it is accidental.
In example I use xpath for this:
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

response = session.get('https://campervans.jeanlain.com/locations/?city-input=annecy&city-name=ANNECY&departure_date=06%2F01%2F2025&departure_time=11%3A00&return_date=10%2F01%2F2025&return_time=10%3A00')
response.html.render()

products = response.html.xpath('//section[contains(@class, "product")]')

for product in products:
    title = product.xpath('.//h2[contains(@class, "woocommerce-loop-product__title")]', first=True)
    if title:
        print(title.text)
    
    price_info = product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "content-right")]', first=True)
    if price_info:
        price = price_info.xpath('.//p[contains(@class, "price")]', first=True)
        if price:
            print(price.text.strip())
        else:
            print(price)
    else:
        print("content-right not found")        

Result:
CITROEN AMENAGE
339,98 €
CITROEN AMENAGE
None
CITROEN AMENAGE
339,98 €
CITROEN AMENAGE
339,98 €
CITROEN AMENAGE
None
VW CALIFORNIA
400,00 €
VW CALIFORNIA
None
VW CALIFORNIA
None
VW CALIFORNIA
None
VW CALIFORNIA AT
None
VW CALIFORNIA 4M AT
None
VW CALIFORNIA 4M AT
400,00 €
VW CALIFORNIA AT
400,00 €
VW CALIFORNIA BEACH
360,00 €


Hello thank you for your answer, it seems to work when adding a "sleep=3" & using the requests-html built-in functions to search data, thank you so much !

You don't need to use something that mimics a browser. You just need to make one extra request. If you go into dev-tools you can see this endpoint and that it is exactly what you need:

Here's the endpoint itself. Use the request library to send a POST request to retrieve data from this endpoint, passing additional parameters :

As a result, if you do it through python, you get something like this:
import requests

response = requests.post(
    'https://campervans.jeanlain.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    },
    data={
        'action': 'products_list_prices',
        'agency': 'annecy',
        'nonce': '839a81d954', # it's nailed down in the html
        'agency_city': 'ANNECY',
        'begin_date': '06/01/2025',
        'begin_hour': '11:00',
        'end_date': '10/01/2025',
        'end_hour': '10:00',
    },
)
data = response.json()

You will be able to pass all keys, except for action and nonce, in a dynamic way. It's then a matter of technique to match this when parsing the html.
for product in products:
    data_immatriculation = product['data-immatriculation']
    title = product.find('h2', class_='woocommerce-loop-product__title')
    price = data.get(data_immatriculation, {}).get('total_price')
    #  if price = None - not available product
    print(f'{price=}')

UPDATED
To fix what you wrote in the comment, you should have just retrieved the data (screenshot1) from the HTML and passed it in a POST request. Or initially store the get request data and pass it on (screenshot2, I'm talking about what's passed through the url).



Hello, thank you for your answer, i was doing this way but the problem is that the ajax-admin.php display price even for unavailable van, so i wanted to find another way...
Thanks to @furas who find the solution !

I've updated the reply. If you write the query correctly, there is no price for an unavailable van, I checked that. I've added why it probably didn't work for you.
